# Image Resizer issue with Azure Functions

Tags: image-processing, azure-blob-storage, imageresizer, azure-functions

I've been following a tutorial on how to resize images using ImageResizer listening to blob storage triggers in Azure Functions. However, i'm getting the following error message:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ImageResizer' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ImageResizer' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> error CS0103: The name 'ImageResizer' does not exist in the current
>   context

My project.json config has been set up as follows:

```
{
"frameworks": {
  "net46":{
    "dependencies": {
      "ImageResizer": "4.0.5"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

and my run code is:

```
#r "System.Drawing"
#r "System.Web"

using ImageResizer;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public static void Run(Stream inputImage, string imageName, Stream outputImage, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{imageName} \n Size: {inputImage.Length} Bytes");

    var settings = new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings{
        MaxWidth = 400,
        Format = "jpg"
    };

    ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(inputImage, outputImage, settings);

}
```

Comment: Has this been resolved by following the recommendations below?

Comment: Nope, although i managed (by a stroke of luck), to find the cause of the issue. I'll answer the question below.

Comment: Can you please share the link to the tutorial that you were following? Did you get it all working in the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue in the end. The problem was, that i had actually called the name of my function 'ImageReizer', which creates a folder with that name in the App Service Plan in the back-end. The problem was, that because it had the same name as the NugetPackage 'ImageResizer', it was getting confused and looking in the project folder instead of the package folder of the same name.

I rebuilt the function with a different name (ImageManipulation) and everything now works as expected.

Comment: Gavin, that's what the comment below Mathew's answer states :) Glad to hear this is working though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like for some reason your **nuget package restore** hasn't happened properly. Using the exact same code as yours above, I'm able to compile this function successfully.

You can force the package restore to happen again by "touching" your **project.json** file. Just make an edit and save it, and you should see the restore happen. On the Develop page for your function, select "View Files", select the project.json file and edit/save. In your log window you should see the restore happen again.

Comment: The fact that the initial NuGet restore failed also leads me to believe that something is incorrectly setup or causing that failure. With the ImageResizer sample, a common issue is to have a function that matches the package name, which makes NuGet treat it as a project reference instead of a package. I've looked at some logs and you may be running into this issue. So, in addition to following Mathew's instructions, please make sure you delete any functions with the name "ImageResizer" and create the function using a different name. This will be addressed in the future.

Comment: You can now also click "Run" in the visual editor in Azure to restore packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure function in version 2.x you need to do this in a different way.

Create a new file and name it function.proj instead of project.json.
Here is an example importing ImageResizer:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ImageResizer" Version="4.2.5" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You can check which runtime version is being used at Azure Portal by clicking on the function name, under Overview tab choose "Function app settings". Runtime version can be ~1 or ~2.